# C# Full text search with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to do a full text search in my win forms application.

```
public static IEnumerable<DataRow> GetPartDataForFullTextSearch(string text1)
{
    using (cEntity context = new cEntity())
    {
        var query = (
            from i in context.tblparts
            join s in context.tblpartstatus on i.partstatus
            equals s.id
            join l in context.tblwarehouse on i.partId
            equals l.partId
            join p in context.tblwarehouseplace on l.warehouseId
            equals p.WhId
            orderby i.partID
            select new Part
            {
                PartNumber = i.partID,
                PartName = i.partName,
                OldPartNo = i.partIdOld,
                Comment = i.comment,
                Hbv = (long)i.HBVNr,
                Status = (int)i.partstatus,
                Building = p.building,
                Room = p.room,
                Shelf = p.shelf,
                CaseOfPart = p.case
            }).Distinct() as IEnumerable<DataRow>;

        var results = 
            from matchingItem in query
            where Regex.IsMatch(matchingItem.Field<string>("partName"), text1)
            select matchingItem;

        var list = results.ToList();

        return list;
    }
}
```

But I don't receive a result => ArgumentNullException

That's how I want to receive the results

```
      private void tbOverviewFullSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgPartOverview.DataSource = 
        DatabaseQueries.D_PartManagement
            .GetPartDataForFullTextSearch(tbOverviewFullSearch.Text);
}
```

What's wrong?
And is it possible to filter more than one field?

Comment: Which O/RM do you use? LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, something else?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot cast an `IQueryable<Part>` to `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Remove the cast and do

```
Regex.IsMatch(matchingItem.partName), text1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but after removing cast ... I received error message "NotSupportedException"??

Comment: That's because `Regex.IsMatch` is now seen as part of the query and EF (which I think you use) can not translate it to SQL. But you can simply fix that by applying `ToList()` after the `Distinct()`.

Comment: Seeing this years later I realize that `ToList` is not the best option. Using `AsEnumerable` instead of `as IEnumerable<DataRow>` should have worked. But it would have been far better to check if the match could have been replaced by a `LIKE` query.